# What's wrong with my database migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite

I'm trying to create a situation in which I have the ability to create a series of studies. So I have a table called Series. Each Series will have a name. Each Series also `has_many :parts`. So I have a table called Part and it `belongs_to :series`. Then each Part `has_many :questions` and my Question table `belongs_to :part`. I have to attribute each of these tables to each other so I have the migrations setup like this:

```
 class CreateSeries < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def self.up
     create_table :series do |t|
       t.string :name


       t.timestamps
     end
   end
   def self.down
       drop_table :series
   end
 end


class CreateParts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :parts do |t|
       t.date :date
       t.string :book
       t.integer :series_id

       t.timestamps
  end
    add_index :parts, [:series_id, :created_at]
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :parts
  end
end



  class CreateQuestions < ActiveRecord::Migration
     def self.up
         create_table :questions do |t|
            t.text :body
            t.integer :part_id

            t.timestamps
         end
            add_index :questions, [:part_id, :created_at]
      end

      def self.down
         drop_table :questions
      end
   end
```

So I migrated the database and using SQLite DB Browser, my Questions table has a `parts_id` which it should. And my Parts table should have a `series_id` column, but it does NOT. Could someone please help with this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why the series column is not in your database. ok to perform a safe check if i may call it try running the model generator again. This time run it like this

`rails g model part date:date book series:belongs_to` and see if you get the same issue. I hope this helps. Or you can also check with your console window try creating a new part with a  random series id and check if it has pluralization issues.

Comment: it is looking like pluralization issues.

Answer (score 0):

Open the application console `rails c` and type `Part`.

You should see the attribute `series_id`.

If you do, the solution is simply restarting the server.

Comment: i tried that and i get this `Part(id: integer, date: date, book: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)`

Comment: Try rolling back and then migrate again. `rake db:rollback && rake db:migrate` (make sure this is your last migration. if not, rollback until this migration get rolled back)

Comment: i've already tried that. i just ran a separate migration `add_column :parts, :series_id, :integer` ... do you think that will be alright? the `series_id` is now showing up in my database. is that something i shouldn't have done or would that work fine?

Comment: Give it a try. Have you changed the migrations any time after a `rake db:migrate`? Or created any migration manually?

Comment: If you can lose the data in development mode, I'd suggest you to drop an recreate the database.

Comment: in the console it now says `Part(id: integer, date: date, book: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, series_id: integer) ` which is good... doing `p = Part.new(:series_id => 1)` gives me an error though. i get `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17157/discussion-between-lucca-mordente-and-jack)